# MongoDB $elemMatch updates the wrong element when an additional query is present

Tags: mongodb

I am facing a weird issue with MongoDB. I am using the official mongo client to use it from NodeJS.

My data sort of looks like this

```
// collection "products"
{
  shop: 'ShopID1',
  customer: ['CustomerID1', 'CustomerID2'],
  products: [
    {product: 'ProductID1', productCount: 10, customer: ['CustomerID1']},
    {product: 'ProductID2', productCount: 5, customer: ['CustomerID2']},
  ]
}
```

Now, I want to remove `'CustomerID2'` from the 2nd product object if it exists on both the outer customer array and in the inner customer array of the 2nd product object.

I can do it with the following query,

```
const productID = 'ProductID2';
const customerID = 'CustomerID2';

db
.collection('products')
.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
        shop: 'ShopID1', 
        // customer: {
        //     $in: [customerID]
        // },
        products: { 
            $elemMatch: { 
                product: productID, 
                customer: {
                    $in: [customerID]
                }
            } 
        },
    },
    {
        $inc: { 
            'products.$.productCount': 1 
        },
        $pull: { 
            'products.$.customer': customerID, 
            customer: customerID
        }
    },
);
```

The problem is, if I uncomment the commented part above, it updates the first product object, which is wrong. I can't find the reason why this happens as my knowledge of Mongo is limited. It seems to me the uncommented part is only adding an additional constraint that should not affect the update operation.

I would also appreciate any feedback on whether this is the correct way to achieve my stated goal. Thanks

Comment: Hi, is below your expected output post deletion? ````// collection "products" post deletion of cusotmerID1 and 2nd object of prouducts
{
  shop: 'ShopID1',
  customer: ['CustomerID1'],
  products: [
    {product: 'ProductID1', productCount: 10, customer: ['CustomerID1']}
  ]
} ````

Comment: @Mallik, I am not sure I get what you are talking about. I think my use case is more about updating than removal

Comment: That code works for me in the shell.  Wiith that section uncommented it increments the count and removes the customer from the second product.  Note that `$in` is not required.  You can query with `customer: customerID` if `customerID` contains a single value.

Comment: Yes. I kept the $in part just for visibility's sake. But for me, the first product gets updated instead of the second one. That's why I'm confused why its happening.

Answer (score 0):

```
//data preparation check
> db.custProducts.find().pretty();
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f5e6d68598d922a1e6eff5c"),
        "shop" : "ShopID1",
        "customer" : [
                "CustomerID1",
                "CustomerID2"
        ],
        "products" : [
                {
                        "product" : "ProductID1",
                        "productCount" : 10,
                        "customer" : [
                                "CustomerID1"
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "product" : "ProductID2",
                        "productCount" : 5,
                        "customer" : [
                                "CustomerID2"
                        ]
                }
        ]
}
//code to remove customerID2 field in both outer array and inner object
//.$. to be used to traverse the document object
> db.custProducts.aggregate([
... {$unwind:"$customer"},
... {$unwind:"$products"},
... {$match:{
...           "shop": "ShopID1",
...           "customer": "CustomerID2",
...           "products.product": "ProductID2"
...      }
...  }
... ]).forEach(function(doc){
...     print("prod: ",doc.products.product);
...     print("cust: ",doc.customer);
...     db.custProducts.update(
...         {"shop": doc.shop, "products.product": "ProductID2" },
...         {$pull:
...             {
...               customer:{$in:[doc.customer]},
...               "products.$.customer":{$in:[doc.customer]}
...            }
...         }
...    );
...   }
...  );
prod:  ProductID2
cust:  CustomerID2
//check the output of the update execution.
> db.custProducts.find().pretty();
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f5e6d68598d922a1e6eff5c"),
        "shop" : "ShopID1",
        "customer" : [
                "CustomerID1"
        ],
        "products" : [
                {
                        "product" : "ProductID1",
                        "productCount" : 10,
                        "customer" : [
                                "CustomerID1"
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "product" : "ProductID2",
                        "productCount" : 5,
                        "customer" : [ ]
                }
        ]
}
>
//further,you can add other logic like $inc in the above code
```